# Running rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s throws socket error

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have been experimenting with setting up a RabbitMQ cluster with Kubernetes.
After doing some research, I stumbled upon the following 2 useful tutorials: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/ and https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-k8s/tree/master/examples/k8s_statefulsets

The first sets up a simple RabbitMQ Service with a ReplicationController and pushes through a test message, while the second goes a bit further and sets up a StatefulSet with RBAC etc.. So far, so good.

However, when I complete the second tutorial, I am trying to push a test message through, like in the first tutorial by running the slightly adjusted commands:

```
export BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
/usr/bin/amqp-declare-queue --url=$BROKER_URL -q foo -d
```

which then throws the error

```
logging in to AMQP server: a socket error occurred
```

At first I thought the URL was wrong, but I verified that it by substituting `rabbitmq` with the ip address feteched using `nslookup rabbitmq` (as demonstrated in the first tutorial).

Could anyone help out on what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: You don't happen to be using tectonic are you?

Comment: No I am not using tectonic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem, it appears the kubernetes guide is outdated: if you use a newer image of unbutu (for example, ubuntu:18.04) when testing, it seems to work!

Comment: Great this worked! The error was "logging in to AMQP server: a socket error occurred" and it seems that the kubernetes tutorial is out of date and when I used the newer version of Ubuntu (18.04 over 14.04) it works! Thanks!